# WordPress get_the_content losing formatting when emailed

Tags: email, content, formatting

I'm pulling the content of a post outside of the loop to send in an email like so:

```
$content = get_the_content();
```

However, when I craft the body of the email:

```
$body =  'Hello:

<br/><br/>

'.get_the_title().' was added to PGOPs Notes. You can view it here:
<br/><br/>

<a href='.get_permalink($post->ID).'>'.get_permalink($post->ID).'</a>
<br/><br/>

'.$pgops_fr_format_assigned_label.'
'.$pgops_fr_trt_label.'
'.$pgops_new_structure_assigned_label.'

'.$content.' 
<br/><br/>

Thank You, <br/>
'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' <br/>
Programming Operations';
```

and send out via wp_mail():

```
wp_mail( $emails, 'New PGOPs Note: '.$title.'', $body, $headers );
```

I lose the formatting for the content variable in the email. An example output for the $content variable should be:

> Reformat for August 2016
>
> (4/28/16)AH - NEW FORMAT BASED ON UPDATED TRT
>
> 2.5 DSCLM / 12B / 13S / 99:55 min max

But what I'm getting in the email is:

> Reformat for August 2016 (4/28/16)AH - NEW FORMAT BASED ON UPDATED TRT2.5 DSCLM / 12B / 13S / 99:55 min max

How do I keep the formatting of the content in my email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default email content type is `text/plain` which does not allow using `HTML`.

Add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
// use HTML instead of plain text
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'my_awesome_mail_content_type' );

function my_awesome_mail_content_type() {

    return 'text/html';
}
```

But be warned, different email clients has very different support for `CSS` rules.. [Read more from here.](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

---

**Alternative:** If you want to keep using `text/plain`, you will need to avoid any `HTML` (*it might break something*) and use `\n` instead of `<br/>` - it's basically the same thing, just a `text/plain` version.

Comment: Thank you. This helped to keep bold formatting, but the line breaks are still missing from the content output.

Comment: And how does this content looks in your site? As far as I know, WordPress eliminates all `<br/>` tags from the content and usually replaces them with `<p>`. Check it out with browser web tools. And your `CSS` isn't magically coming along, you would need to add inline `CSS` but all this is whole new topic and question.

Comment: If I view the post on the site, the content displays correctly formatted. So, based on your alternative answer, can I simply return to using text/plain and search/replace `<br/>` with `\n`?

Comment: You couldn't replace them if that same content is also shown in your webpage. Adding that content to your email is tricky one way or the other, because WordPress converts line breakers to `<p>`. This should be another question in my opinion, you will need to code a function that filters and formats you content. Or you could try to replace all `<br/>` with `<p style="margin: 0 0 1em;">&nbsp;</p>` .

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like I will need to do as you suggested, code a function that filters and formats the content just for emails. While this particular post type does not get shown on the website, that doesn't mean that all of the other content types we have on the site are also not shown on the website. I appreciate your insight!

Comment: The line break fix for me was to do as you mentioned with a custom filtering function. I ran the output of `get_the_content()` through the `nl2br()` function before sending it to `wp_email()` and the output returned as I needed it to. Thank you again!